# toLocaleLowerCase() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

when I use the method toLocaleLowerCase it gives me an error that it is not a method.

Here is my html

```html
<div id="cards_main"></div>
```

And here is my **JS**

```js
let arry = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value != "") {
    for (cards of arry) {
      if (cards.naming.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]).toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        document.querySelector("#cards_main").innerHTML = "";
        addCard(cards);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the array is not empty

Comment: Which part of your code is that error referring to? Have you tried debugging it? Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. For example: what is `i`? What does `cards` look like? Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: It seems like `cards.naming` is not a string, which causes the error to be thrown. Ensure your object has a string field called `naming`. You can add an if statement to check this with `if (typeof cards.naming === 'string' && cards.naming.toLocaleLowerCase()`

Comment: Probably a typo. The latter `.toLocaleLowerCase()` is called on the return value of `.startsWith()`, which returns a boolean. You probably meant to call it on the `.value` of `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]`?

Comment: @MisterJojo as I have mentioned my array is not empty in the code

Comment: I will try that @AriSeyhun

Comment: I will check again @Ivar

Comment: @BahramGozalov see my answer, it looks like your final call to toLocaleLowerCase isn't valid on a boolean.

Comment: @AriSeyhun thanks it worked I will accept it as a correct answer ASAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.

The [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method returns a boolean of `true` or `false`, and expects a string. In your case you are passing a HTML element to it.

Try instead:

```js
.startsWith(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value)
```

[`.toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) should be run on a string type, but you are running it on a boolean.

```js
if (cards
      .naming
      .toLocaleLowerCase()
      .startsWith(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]) // This returns a boolean
      .toLocaleLowerCase() // But this line isn't valid on a boolean
    ) {
```

You likely wanted to call `toLocaleLowerCase` on your input value.

Try this code instead:

```js
const inputValue = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;
if (cards.naming.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue.toLocaleLowerCase())) {
  // ...
}
```